# How my network will differ from bitcoin

Tags: p2p, bitcoin

I read a lot about how bitcoin clients find each other. I would like to do a fork from bitcoin and I have a question. How my network will differ from bitcoin? How the node found by my client will understand if this is bitcoin's client or mine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How my network will differ from bitcoin?

You will need to change the `network magic` for your protocol messages so the nodes on the bitcoin network can easily distinguish your network messages and theirs.

https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Protocol_documentation#Message_structure

> How the node found by my client will understand if this is bitcoin's client or mine?

Assuming you are using the same protocol as in Bitcoin, once you change the `network magic` field, it should be sufficient for your fork to distinguish between messages intended for Bitcoin network and your network.